# Is there an analytic function with zeroes only at $-2n$, and zeroes at $\frac12\pm it$, and further, symmetric zeroes within the critical strip?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

> Is there an analytic function with zeroes **only** at:

- every $-2n$,
- $\frac12\pm it$, and
- at least one at $\frac12\pm\epsilon\pm it$ where $0<\epsilon<\frac12, t\neq0$ (and these zeroes observing the known reflective symmetries within the critical strip)?

A answer assuming the Riemann hypothesis true would be fine.

To my mind the uniqueness of any analytic continuation of $\zeta(s)$ is suggestive of the existence of such a function being incompatible with the Riemann Hypothesis.

If not, uniqueness of $\zeta$ is of course a nice simple sufficiency for the Riemann hypothesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $\zeta(z)\left(z-\frac14-i\right)\left(z-\frac14+i\right)\left(z-\frac34-i\right)\left(z-\frac34+i\right)$.

Every condition that you mentioned holds.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is an open question. As long as your function is automorphic, the Grand Riemann Hypothesis asks this exact question.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. Does the Grand Riemann Hypothesis ask if this is the case, *and permit one to assume the Riemann hypothesis*? Because if not, it would seem a potentially important result, if it were true, that to prove GRH assuming RH, would prove RH.

Comment: That doesn't sound right.